# WindowState change while using Prism with MVVM

Tags: mvvm, prism

similar to the scenario mentioned in the question: [Binding the "WindowState" property of a window in WPF using MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4671368/binding-the-windowstate-property-of-a-window-in-wpf-using-mvvm)

Using Prism (views,modules,shell) 
I have a Shell.xaml (belongs to WPFProject) which loads 2 views in order:

1. LoginView.xaml(usercontrol) from SecurityModule(another classlibrary project)
2. MainScreenView.xaml(usercontrol) from ProductModule(another classlibrary project) - on click of "Sign-in" button on LoginView.xaml

The LoginView.xaml is smaller like width=300, height=300. But the MainScreenView.xaml needs to be displayed in maximized size.

Now to display MainScreenView.xaml on the shell, the windowstate needs to be maximized.

How can I expose the Shell WindowState property, so that I can change while loading views on the shell using Prism with MVVM?

Refer the sample Prism MVVM example from the link : http://weblogs.asp.net/sujithkjagini/archive/2011/02/02/building-applications-with-wpf-and-prism-aka-cag.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is using events of Prism. Prism contains an EventAggregator which permits communication between modules. You can find an example at the end of the page that you linked in the post, but it can be not so clear. This other link might help you [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921173%28v=PandP.40%29.aspx)